# Android app not taking pictures and saving them to an SQLite database

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, android-camera

My app should be taking pictures using the camera and then saving them to an SQLite database. This is done by opening the camera taking the picture after which the images is returned to an image view the user then clicks save to persist the image to the database.

**The problem**

After the image is returned to the image view and the user clicks the save button the app freezes with the only thing being displayed is "Unfortunately, Dress(the name of the app) has stopped responding" there are no errors in the.

**What have i tried**

I have tried doing a little debugging by commenting our the functions and i have narrowed it down to the db.open() function so it seems as if once it tries to make any connection to the databse it freezes. I have never worked with android or android databases (Expert level noob) before and i have done more than sufficient and still can't solve the problem.

this is what i've been using as my tutorial

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xq8m82zgt1s

```
//This file triggers the camera returns the images and makes the call to the database
package dress.advance;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Upload extends Activity {
    protected static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 0;
    protected static final int CAMERA_ACTIVITY = 0;
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    protected static final String Upload = null;
    private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    private int count = 0;
    private Uri fileUri;
    DBAdapter link;
    ImageView CaputredImage;
    ImageView browsedImage;
    Bitmap theCapturedImage;
     private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        browsedImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageBrowse);

        Button browseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browse);

        browseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), SELECT_IMAGE);

                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);



        }       
    });

        Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageSaveButton);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                if(!(CaputredImage == null)){

                    Img testim = new Img(theCapturedImage, "img"+getCount());           
                    link.open();
                    /*link.createImgEntry(testim);
                    link.close();
                    */
                }
            }

        });


        CaputredImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageCapture);


        //Declaration of button to link to camera trigger
        Button CaptureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture);
        //Listener for button
        CaptureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent startCamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(startCamera, 0);

                Intent mIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);   
                mIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, 
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString()); 
                startActivityForResult(mIntent, CAMERA_ACTIVITY);

            }       
        });

    }






protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{


    if(requestCode == 0){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //setCount(getCount() + 1);
        theCapturedImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        CaputredImage.setImageBitmap(theCapturedImage);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(Upload); // create a file to save the image
        data.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
        Img testim = new Img(theCapturedImage, "img"+getCount());

        link.open();
        link.createImgEntry(testim);
        link.close();

    }
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        browsedImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(cr, "", "name", "now"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }}

    private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(String upload2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

}    





    // this is my db helpper
    package dress.advance;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import android.util.Log;



public class DBAdapter {

    public final static String Key_ROWID = "_id";
    public final static String Key_NAME = "name";
    public final static String TAG = "socialNatwork";
    public final static String DATABASE_NAME = "SocialNetwork";
    public final static String Key_IMG = "image";

    public final static String DATABASE_TABLE = "PESITIMAGE";

    public final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //i think the problem might be here 
    public final static String DATABASE_CREATES =
            "create table PESITIMAGE(_id integer primary key autoincrement, image BLOB not null, name text not null);  ";



    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Context context;

    public DBAdapter (Context ctx){
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        DatabaseHelper(Context context){

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "Creating the database");
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATES);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.w(TAG, "upgrading database from version" + oldVersion 
                    + " to" 
                    + newVersion +", which will destroy all data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST PESITIMAGE");
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }

        public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException{
            Log.i(TAG, "opening the database");
            db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;

        }

        public void close(){
            Log.i(TAG, "closing the database");
            db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            DBHelper.close();

        }

        public void createImgEntry(Img img){
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            img.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(Key_IMG, out.toByteArray());
            cv.put(Key_NAME, img.getName());
            long j = db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
            Log.i("Sakshi", String.valueOf(j));
        }

        public Img getFirstImgFormats() throws SQLException{
            Cursor cur = db.query(true, 
                    DATABASE_TABLE,
                    new String[]{Key_IMG, Key_NAME},
                    null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if(cur.moveToFirst()){
                byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(Key_IMG));
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Key_NAME));

                cur.close();
                return new Img(bmp,name);
            }
            cur.close();
            return null;

        }

        public Img getImgFromDB(String n) throws SQLException{
            Cursor cur = db.query(true,
                    DATABASE_TABLE,
                    new String[]{Key_IMG, Key_NAME},
                    Key_NAME+"=\""+n+"\"", null, null, null, null, null);
            if(cur.moveToFirst()){
                byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(Key_IMG));
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Key_NAME));
                cur.close();
                return new Img(bmp,name);
            }
            cur.close();
            return null; 

        }

        public Img getImg() throws SQLException{
            Cursor cur = db.query(true, 
                    DATABASE_TABLE,
                    new String[]{Key_IMG, Key_NAME},
                    null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if(cur.moveToLast()){
                byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(Key_IMG));
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Key_NAME));

                cur.close();
                return new Img(bmp,name);
            }
            cur.close();
            return null;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are storing the images in a database instead of a file? SQLite databases aren't really intended for storing data such as imagery. A more typical use-case would be saving the image to the phone's internal storage or SD card, then storing the path in the database.

Comment: try using a AsyncTask to do DB operations.

Comment: make sure that you can store images into two ways either using BLOB Data type or take file path of that image stored in the SD card. I will suggest you to choose to choose second option filepath.

Comment: why don't you declare all findviewbyid at the top of your all code inside onCreate, it may be null pointer exception because of "CaputredImage" has not declare.